# Fastest way to solve a linear sytem of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

What is the fastest way to solve a linear system of equations if we wave 3 equations and 3 unknowns?

Gaussian elimination seems to be faster, cramers, is there any others faster method

Comment: Any way is  fast when the coefficients are "bad". However in practice, Gaussian is the fastest.

Comment: It depends on the linear equations. The subtraction/addition method  can work here very efficiently.